# Template class operator overloading: Which way should I take an argument of the same class?

Tags: c++, templates, arguments, operator-overloading

When overloading class operators which take the same class as argument, as far as I know, there are three different ways. In the first way, the argument is not passed by any specific template type. In the second way, the argument template type is explicitly given to be the same. And in the third way, we allow the template type to be something else.

I can guess that the third one can be used for catching different type of classes, and when there is no implicit conversion between the template types. But, what is the difference between the first one and the other ones? What happens when we don't give a specific template type for the argument (as seen in the first format)? Can you please compare these three formats?

```
#include <iostream>

template <class T>
class MyNumber
{
    public:
        MyNumber(const T & Value);

        // Format 1:
        // The argument is taken without specifying any template argument.
        MyNumber operator+(const MyNumber       & Another);

        // Format 2:
        // The argument is taken with the same type of template argument.
        MyNumber operator-(const MyNumber<T>    & Another);

        // Format 3:
        // The argument is taken with a different type of template argument.
        template <class U>
        MyNumber operator*(const MyNumber<U>    & Another);

        T Value;
};

template <class T>
MyNumber<T>::MyNumber(const T & Value)
    : Value(Value)
{
}

template <class T>
MyNumber<T> MyNumber<T>::operator+(const MyNumber & Another)
{
    return MyNumber<T>(this->Value + Another.Value);
}

template <class T>
MyNumber<T> MyNumber<T>::operator-(const MyNumber<T> & Another)
{
    return MyNumber<T>(this->Value - Another.Value);
}

template <class T>
template <class U>
MyNumber<T> MyNumber<T>::operator*(const MyNumber<U> & Another)
{
    return MyNumber<T>(this->Value * static_cast<T>(Another.Value));
}

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[])
{
    Chronometer Timer;

    MyNumber<int> Number1(40);
    MyNumber<int> Number2(10);

    std::cout << "Number  1  : " << Number1.Value               << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Number  2  : " << Number2.Value               << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result (+) : " << (Number1 + Number2).Value   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result (-) : " << (Number1 - Number2).Value   << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Result (*) : " << (Number1 * Number2).Value   << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The code successfully compiles on Visual Studio 2015 and the code output is as expected:

```
Number  1  : 40
Number  2  : 10
Result (+) : 50
Result (-) : 30
Result (*) : 400
```

Comment: Now try to mix `MyNumber<int>` and `MyNumber<float>`. You'll answer all your questions yourself.

Comment: Why do you `static_cast<U>`? It's already `U`

Comment: @Drop It was a typo. Fixed it. Thanks.

Comment: You are basically asking what the difference is between `template<T> void C<T>::f(const C&)` and  `template<T> void C<T>::f(const C<T>&)` (i.e. the `<T>` in the argument)? Can you please strip your question of all things that are irrelevant for your problem?